# extract number of products on first day of month and keep the result excel

Tags: excel, formula

my number of products now it is 83 (cell A3). i want to extract and keep the number of cell A3 in cell C3, if date of cell B3 is equal with first day of moth, in my case 11/01/2017 (cell C2). please help me with right formula but pay attention, i want to keep the result from C3 even if date of B3 is changing on every day. thank you!

[image: this is my example]

Answer (score 0):

As Excel formulas rely on the values in a cell, there's no way to write a formula to check for values, and then freeze the result as part of the formula.  So you really only have two options.

**Option 1**

Manually copy / paste-values the value in A3 to C3 when the date is the first of the month.

**Option 2**

You will need to use VBA code to accomplish this.  To access the VBA editor, you can press Alt+F11 or go into the Developer Tab of the ribbon.  Once inside, navigate to the sheet that holds your data, probably sheet1.  In the top of the editor, look for where it says (General) and (Declarations).  Set (General) to "Worksheet" and then where it says (Declarations) set it to "Change".

In the sub-routine that appears called Private Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range), insert the following code

```
If Target = Sheet1.range("$B$3") and Target.value = Sheet1.range("$C$2").value Then

    Sheet1.range("$C$3").value = Sheet1.range("$A$3").value

End If
```

This sub is actually an event handler in that it runs every time something in Sheet1 changes.  Excel sends the cell that was changed as the "Target" range to the sub-routine.  The sub is actually pretty simple, it first checks to make sure that the cell is Cell $B$3 in Sheet1 and then checks to see if it matches the date you have in cell $C$2.  If it matches then the macro will make the $C$3 cell the value of the $A$3 cell, without using a formula.  This way, even when cell $A$3 changes, cell $C$3 won't.

I hope helps answer your question.  Good luck in your Excel endeavors!